# Assign a struct element to other cmm local variable

Tags: trace32

I'am using cmm scripts and i want to assign a struct element to other cmm mocal variable like that

&Intermidiate = Debug_Log[0].Name

But i had always the Error as it is shown in the picture[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J7F5.png)

structure element assignes to local cmm variable

Answer (score 1):

`Debug_Log[0].Name` is a HLL expression. Those expressions are only valid for TRACE32 commands starting with `Var.`.

To use the value of a HLL expression with any other command, wrap it in the function `VAR.VALUE(<hllexpr>)`.
 E.g. like this:

```
 &Intermidiate=Var.VALUE(Debug_Log[0].Name)
```